# Play2 performance surprises

Tags: performance, scala, amazon-ec2, playframework, playframework-2.0

Some introduction first.

Our **Play2** (ver. 2.5.10) web service provides responses in JSON, and the response size can be relatively large: up to 350KB.

We've been running our web service in a standalone mode for a while. We had gzip compression enabled as **Play2**, which reduces response body ~10 times, i.e. we had up to ~35KB response bodies.

In that mode the service can handle to up to 200 queries per second while running on AWS EC2 m4.xlarge (4 vCPU, 16GB RAM, 750 MBit network) inside Docker container. The performance is completely CPU-bound, most of the time (75%) is spent on JSON serialization, and rest of the time (25%) was spent on gzip compression. Business logic is very fast and is not even visible on the perf graphs.

Now we have introduced a separate front-end node (running **Nginx**) to handle some specific functions: authentication, authorization and, crucially to this question, traffic compression. We hoped to offload compression from the Play2 back-end to the front-end and spend those 25% of CPU cycles on main tasks.

However, instead of improving, performance got much worse! Now our web service can only handle up to 80 QPS. At that point, most of CPU is already consumed by something inside the JVM. Our metrics show it's not garbage collection, and it's also not in our code, but rather something inside Play.

It's important to notice that as this load (80 QPS at ~350KB per response) we generate ~30 MB/s of traffic. This number, while significant, doesn't saturate the EC2 networking, so that shouldn't be the bottleneck.

So my question, I guess, is as follows: does anyone have an explanation and a mitigation plan for this problem? Some hints about how to get to the root cause of this would also be helpful.

Comment: just curious, of course the logic is the same, you just remove gzip from play2 config, right?

Comment: Right, it's just a gzip filter removed/added.